# Three.js multiple layers and selective lighting with effect composer

Tags: three.js

I have a scene involving several planets rotating around a sun.  In order to get the lighting right (and allow planets to cast a shadow on their own rings) I have each planet in its own layer, each with its own directional light shining from the direction of the sun.  Now, I want to add an effects composer to the scene, but I can't figure out how to render it correctly so that all the layers show up.  This is my current animation loop, which works:

```
renderer.autoClear = false

animate() {

    this.camera.layers.set(0) 
    renderer.render(scene, this.camera)
    
    this.camera.layers.set(1) 
    renderer.render(scene, this.camera)
    
    this.camera.layers.set(2) 
    renderer.render(scene, this.camera)

    this.camera.layers.set(3)
    renderer.render(scene, this.camera)

    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

But I can't figure out how to add the effects composer on top of all that.  I have tried adding a separate camera for each layer and a renderPass for each camera:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.camera[i] = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera()
        this.camera[i].layers.set(i)
        let renderPass = new RenderPass(scene, this.camera[i])
        composer.addPass( renderPass )   
    }

    animate() {
        composer.render()
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
```

But when I do this, only the final layer is visible.  How do I avoid erasing the previous layers?

Comment: Are you rendering a background color, or is your `WebGLRenderer` configured with `alpha: true`?

Comment: Also, you might have this in your full code, but you should be clearing the buffers before drawing a new frame with `renderer.clear()` before the first `renderer.render(scene, this.camera)`.

Comment: @TheJim01 I edited to show specifically what's not working.

Comment: Interesting. I wrote my own minimal example, and was able to get layers and the effect composer rendering the same output individually, but not together. You might want to take this over to the official forum (https://discourse.threejs.org/) as a potential bug or enhancement. Caveat: `EffectComposer` _is_ an _example_, so it probably holds lower development priority than core modules.